# Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^{n-\frac{1}{2}}}$ locally integrable over $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am not really sure how to write.

The case for n=1 is obvious (or maybe I'm mistaken), but I'm kinda of confused for higher orders.

For **n=1**, 
$\int_{[a,b]} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 2\sqrt{b} - 2\sqrt{a}$

Comment: Yes. Do polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is constant on spherical shells around $0$. Denote the $(n-1)$-dimensional surface of $S^{n-1}\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ by $\omega_{n-1}$. Then
$$\int_{B_1}{1\over|x|^{n-1/2}}\ {\rm d}(x)=\omega_{n-1}\int_0^1{1\over r^{n-1/2}}\>r^{n-1}\>dr=\omega_{n-1}\int_0^1{1\over\sqrt{r}}\>dr=2\omega_{n-1}<\infty\ ,$$
by Fubini's theorem.